# ASP.NET MVC - Change appsettings tag location from webConfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I will need to remove the appsettings tag from the webconfig and put it elsewhere, but how do I find this new location in the code?

My app settings:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="TimeEditDeleteApont" value="180" />
    <add key="TimeStockApont" value="180" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="AdminUserName" value="Admin@Admin.com" />
    <add key="AdminPassword" value="Password#1" />
    <add key="TempUploadFolder" value="~/content/upload/temp" />
    <!--<add key="FinalUploadFolder" value="~/content/images/apontamento" />-->
    <add key="AllowedFiles" value=".ppt,.pttx,.pdf,.jpeg,.jpg,.gif,.png,.doc,.docx,.xls,.xlsx" />
    <add key="MaxFileSizeMegaByte" value="25" />
  </appSettings>
```

How i use inside my code:

```
  public BaseController()
        {
            ViewBag.FinalUploadFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("FinalUploadFolder");
            ViewBag.TempUploadFolder = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TempUploadFolder");

        }

public string TimeConfig
        {
            get
            {

                return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TimeEditDeleteApont"];
            }
        }
```

How can I change the location of appSettings and then find that location within the code?

After I create a config file at the root of the folder, how do I find it inside the code?

Comment: "I will need to remove the appsettings tag from the webconfig and put it elsewhere"...why, exactly? Let's go back a step because this is, on the face of it, a slightly bizarre requirement.

Comment: @ADyson Because I will not be able to subscribe to webconfig after each deployment. And after the deploy I will not have access to the webconfig file, so if I need to change any parameter in appsettings I will have to overwrite the webconfig and delete some settings made by the server team

Comment: It sounds like your deployment process is flawed. Why would settings need to be added to web config by another team after deployment? They should be added as part of the build process surely, _before_ deployment. (And if they are only needed in a certain environment, then that can be achieved by using config transforms and build configurations in visual studio.)

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody needs to separate the `<appSettings>` from the `webConfig` file, I did it as follows:

I created a `appSettings.config` file at the root of the project and then at `<appSettings>` I pointed to this file as follows:

```
<appSettings 
    configSource="appSettings.config">        
</appSettings>
```